# how to debug dotnet ef database drop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

On Running `dotnet ef database drop` I get an error. How can I debug this command, to get more details about the problem? Or how can I find the source of this error?

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
>   Objektname: "ApplicationDbContext".
>      bei Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
>      bei Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure.get_Instance()
>      bei Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
>      bei Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
>      bei Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
>      bei Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.DropDatabase(String contextType)
>      bei Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.DropDatabaseImpl(String contextType)
>      bei Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.DropDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>      bei Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
>   Objektname: "ApplicationDbContext".

Comment: I'd [file a bug on their GitHub page](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues).

Comment: How does the `DbContext` get initialized? Are you migrating against a ASP.NET Core project or a class library? If it's ASP.NET Core, post your `Startup` class. If it's a class library, post your `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` implementation.

Comment: My main question is: Can I somehow run `dotnet ef ...` in the debugger?

Comment: Try running dotnet ef database drop --force

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem and added this to the DbContext:

```
private void PrintStackTrace()
{
  var st = new StackTrace();
  foreach (var sf in st.GetFrames())
    Console.WriteLine($"{sf.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Assembly.GetName().Name} {sf.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name} {sf.GetMethod().Name}");
}
```

and call this function in the contructor and Dispose of the DbContext.

It seems to be a problem, if the DbContext is added with scoped lifetime to the dependency injection. I filed an issue for that.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10693

Comment: The problem is fixed with EF Core 2. There won't be a fix for EF Core 1.1.

Answer (score 3):

An addition to aqua from mars' answer:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("Current ProcessID: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id); //This prints the process id
Console.Out.WriteLine("Waiting for debugger to attach...");
while (!Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
Console.Out.WriteLine("Debugger attached!");
```

This code can be added anywhere in your code that will be run, in my case an implementation of **IDesignTimeServices**. Paste it to the constructor or anywhere before the first breakpoint, you want to hit...

Then either use

- Visual Studio: Debug->Attach to Process
- Jetbrains Rider: Run->Attach to Process
- any other debugger which is aware of attaching to a running process you are familiar with

The console output will tell you the process id which makes it easy to find the correct process immediatelly. Usually, several dotnet process will be listed, especially when debugging something like

```
dotnet ef ...
```

Answer (score 2):

add the code to wait for a debugger in your DbContext constructor and you'll be able to debug :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        while (!Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then attach the dotnet process using your favorite debugger.